# How do I install react and react-redux onto my project?

Tags: npm

Good afternoon,

I am trying to install react and react-redux onto my project, but I keep getting errors that I don't understand.

```
$ npx create-react-app learn-redux
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "Phelps\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\13464" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Taylor Phelps\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-08T20_44_17_568Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1
```

```
Could not install from "Phelps\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\13464" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

I am reading the error, but the problem is...that folder does not exist on my computer and I've checked in the terminal for npm and npx and both are installed on my computer. Does anyone have any ideas on why this may be happening and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/146) Github issue `npx` has trouble running on Windows if the user has a space in their name and from the error message I'd guess that is the case here. One of the suggested fixes is to set your `npm-cache` path to a folder without a space in it:

```
npm config set cache C:\tmp\nodejs\npm-cache --global
```

Then try running your command again.

Answer (score 1):

Install the project in another directory except C partition :

```
npx create-react-app learnredux
```

Then :

```
npm i react-redux --save
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the npm cache by the path of the error. Try running:

```
npm cache verify
```

> Verify the contents of the cache folder, garbage collecting any
>   unneeded data, and verifying the integrity of the cache index and all
>   cached data.

(from https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/cache.html)